# Number of roots of f(x) = $\Sigma_{r=1}^{2009} \frac{r}{x-r}$

Tags: functions, polynomials, summation

This question is from a practice workbook for a college entrance exam.

State whether true or false -
The number of times the function $f(x) = \Sigma_{r=1}^{2009} \frac{r}{x-r}$ vanishes is 2008.

I rewrote $\frac{r}{x-r}$ as $\frac{x}{x-r} - 1$
This brings the equation to $x \Sigma_{r=1}^{2009}\frac{1}{x-r} = 2009.$
Now I notice that this sigma notation can be reached if I took the logarithm of a polynomial with roots 1,2,3,...,2009 and differentiated.
So $$\Sigma_{r=1}^{2009} \frac{1}{x-r} = \frac{2009}{x} = \frac{1}{x^{2009} + ax^{2008} +...+ 2009!}$$
We need to find the number of values of x that can satisfy this.
But I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: A natural place to start would be to solve it for numbers smaller than $2009$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function has vertical asymptotes at each $x = 1,2,3, \cdots , 2009$. At each interval $I_k = [k, k+1], k = 1, \cdots 2008$, you have that:
$$
\lim_{x\to k^+} f(x)=+\infty, \quad \lim_{x\to (k+1)^-}f(x) = -\infty, \quad f'(x) < 0.
$$

This proves that there is exactly one root at each interval $I_k$, hence 2008 roots in the interval $[1, 2009]$. To complete the proof you must show that there are no roots outside this interval.

Comment: So for numbers greater than 2009, I could reason that each and every term of $\Sigma \frac{r}{x-r}$ will be positive and hence cannot sum to zero and vice verse for numbers less than 1. Did I get that right?

Comment: @G12inIndia Yes, that does the trick.